# How to create a folder on shared drive in Google Drive using C#

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I would like to create a new folder on another shared drive using c#, everything works on my drive only.
I use this code.

```
                var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
                {
                    Name = folderName,
                    MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
                    Parents = new List<string>() { folderTargetID },
                };

                // Create a new folder on drive.
                var request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata);
                request.Fields = "id";
                var folderInfo = request.Execute();
```

please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After i add some code, finally works fine.

```
                // File metadata
                var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
                {
                    Name = folderName,
                    MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
                    Parents = new List<string>() { folderTargetID },
                };

                // Create a new folder on drive.
                var request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata);
                request.SupportsAllDrives = true;
                request.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
                request.Fields = "id";
                var folderInfo = request.Execute();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).